# AWS Lambda - Is it possible to restrict an IAM role to create functions with a particular prefix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I'm adding an IAM role for a SaaS vendor, who has read-only access except for the ability to create Lambda functions.

Initially they requested a broad set of permissions for Lambda:

```
"Statement": [
{
  "Action": [
    "lambda:CreateFunction",
    "lambda:DeleteFunction",
    "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    "lambda:UpdateFunctionCode",
    "lambda:UpdateFunctionConfiguration"
  ],
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": "*"
},
```

I am uncomfortable with allowing this kind of access over resources they don't own, i.e. our business-critical functions.

When I raised this with them, they said that all their functions will be prefixed with their company name (e.g. `company_prefix`), so I thought I might be able to do this:

```
...
"Resource": "arn:aws:lambda::<account>:function:company_prefix*"
...
```

But reviewing the policy in the console editor suggests a problem:
[image: IAM Policy Editor]

Is this not going to work? Is it possible to restrict Lambda function permissions in this way?

Comment: Try it and see! Let us know what you find. Also, please note that they might not be able to use the management console, but they can continue to make API calls (eg via the AWS CLI or SDKs).

Comment: Going through it with their engineers this arvo :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, IAM does support [resource-level permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html) for Lambda.

I tested a variant of your policy on a new IAM user. For Lambda function names matching the wildcard, I was successful. For non-matching function names I got `AccessDeniedException`.

I did not test all the listed Lambda actions (just `GetFunctionConfiguration` because it was simple to test) so please test that this does what you need.

Note: when you test this you will need to be patient as IAM policy changes do not always take effect immediately.